# What are the difference between these 2 wireless hardware?

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, pci

[image]

On the left is **Intel 512AN** and
on the right is **Atheros AR9285**

Altough i'm currently using the Atheros, but
both are having different size, and i tried both can be plugged 
into the slot of my laptop.

But i never tried to switch on my laptop using Intel 512AN. I wonder, Did anybody has tried so far whether is it working?

Which one is the mini pci, mini pci-e, mini pci-e half?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which one is the mini pci, mini pci-e, mini pci-e half?

Neither device is a Mini PCI Card.  PCI and PCI-E are completely different standards.  The Intel Card based on its size is a PCI Express Mini Card.

> Dimensions of PCI Express Mini Cards are 30 × 50.95 mm (width × length) for a Full Mini Card. There is a 52-pin edge connector, consisting of two staggered rows on a 0.8 mm pitch.

The Atheros Card based on its size is a Half PCI Express Mini Card.

> A "Half Mini Card" (sometimes abbreviated as HMC) is also specified, having approximately half the physical length of 26.8 mm.

Both devices are Mini PCI Express which means they both will work unless the OEM has blacklisted one of the devices and/or they are both not on the whitelist of allowed devices which can happen with these particular type of devices.

> Did anybody has tried so far whether is it working?

Source: Wikipedia - [PCI Express](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#MINI-CARD)

Comment: thanks for the details you gave @Ramhound,... so if the Atheros inserted into the Full Mini Card will it be working?
And how about if the Intel inserted into the Half Mini Card,.... would it be working as well....?

If it's just a matter of space, user can easily hack their physical (plastic laptop case) to use one of it (either half / full) if they just have one slot only. right? :D

Comment: What? You said they both were being installed into the same location and you already verified they fit.  You can't change your question on us like that.  If you do this answer gets deleted and then I vote to close the question as being unclear.